# Quicktime appear when play mp3 file in webview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, mp3, quicktime

when i use a webview to play an mp3 file, the quick time player appears. However, i notice that this does not necessarily happen to other devices i.e., for other iphones, the mp3 file continue playing but the quick time player does not appear. As a result, user is unable to fast forward/pause etc. the mp3 file.

Is there any way that i can strictly enforce that the quicktime player appears?

Here is my code
    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: self.url];

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myUrl  cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 10];

NSLog(@"Play URL: %@", self.url);
UIWebView *webView2 = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView2 loadRequest: request];

[request release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact the quick time player didn't appear may well be a bug. It's a know bug in one of the iOS 5.0 beta releases. Normally WebKit will detect the content type from the HTTP header or file extension and open the AVPlayer from there. You could try using an `NSMutableURLRequest` and setting the content type header.

`[[myRequest headers] setObject:@"video/mp4" forKey:@"Content-Type"]`

Comment: Thanks, can I have an example of nsmutableurlrequest content type header?

Comment: Added a pseudo example above.

Comment: i tried it but xcode warns me with -headers method not found. Sorry i think i know what you are trying to drive at, just that i might need the specific code... thanks!

Comment: I also realized that the quicktime appear for iOS4.2.1, but for iOS4.3 and above, the player does not appear anymore